# What's this comp. sci. prob. called?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, theory

I thought of this problem with some real use cases, but since I have no idea what it's called I cannot find any information about it. If it resembles some known computer science problem someone else has probably done a better solution than me.

I have a pile of lego, containing bricks of various kinds. There might be any number of bricks of any given type. I also have a set of designs/things I could build with lego, each with a list of the pieces required.

What can I build with my pile of lego? (one at a time)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer science and not programming. It may be appropriate for [programmers.se] instead.

Comment: @KenWhite, how about migrating to http://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @shuttle87: Yes, [cs.se] would work also. :-)

Comment: It doesn't have a name because it's trivial: "is this set a subset of this other set?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multidimensional range query problem.  If k is the number of brick types, then each design can be represented by a k-dimensional point (length-k array) whose co-ordinates are the required numbers of each type of brick, and what you are looking for is the set of all points in the database having co-ordinates less than the corresponding co-ordinates of your query point (x_1, ..., x_k), which corresponds to your heap.  Another way of saying this is that you're looking for the set of points in the hyperrectangle bounded by (0, ..., 0) - (x_1, ..., x_k).